# How does firstOrNew looks for records on the database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have an existing record on my table:

```
company_id       first_name      last_name         age    
DCI-201812001      John             Doe            27
```

What I want is that, if I insert new record, I want to check if the record is new or to be updated by checking the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `age`.

I used `firstOrNew` method in Laravel, however, when I tried to insert a record with the ff. values:

```
first_name = "John"
last_name = "Doe"
age = 29
```

Laravel's `firstOrNew` thinks that it is the same as my existing record stated above.

This is my controller:
[image]

Screenshots

1. This is what being retrieved when I inserted a record somewhat the same with the existing record.
   `first_name = "John"`,  `last_name = "Doe"`, `age = 29`. It retrieved the existing record. Why does it retrieves the existing record when the age column is different? Why it doesn't consider the age that I passed?

[image]

> **Please disregard question number 2. I realized that if record is not
>   found, it returns a new instance of the model.**

2. This is what being retrieved when I inserted a completely different record.
   `first_name = "Felicita"`,  `last_name = "Ignacio"`, `age = 25`. Why does the age column become null when I passed a value 25 on age column on the form?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. It means we have to type it all out, and it isn't searchable.

Comment: I'll take note on this one the next time I ask a question. Thanks anyway, you're a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `first_name`, `last_name`, and `age` need to be like this:

```
[
    'first_name' => ...,
    'last_name' => ...,
    'age' => ...,
]
```

not like this:

```
['first_name' => ...],
['last_name' => ...],
['age' => ...],
```

You're sending three separate arrays as three separate arguments. You should be sending one array as the *first* argument.

(The second argument for `firstOrNew` is an additional array of default values to set if the `orNew` part executes.)